# Improvised self-raising flour

Tags: substitutions, flour

Say I just ran out of self-raising flour. What can I add to plain flour to make the equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

According to http://southernfood.about.com/cs/breads/ht/self_rise_flour.htm, you would add 1.5 teaspoons baking powder and 1/2 teaspoon salt to each cup of flour.

Salt is only added to US self-**rising** flour. In the UK, where it's called self-**raising flour** there is no salt added to the flour itself.

Comment: I've done this, and it works just fine. You can sift to make sure the additional ingredients filter through, or you can simply use a fork or whisk.

Comment: While it works as above, note that self-raising flour is generally softer wheat than all purpose flour (matters with biscuits and cakes) and the manufacturers have access to more kinds of leavenings than you do.  So while the fix will work, there is still a good reason to keep the self-rising flour around.