# Improvising Self-rising cornmeal

Tags: baking, substitutions

This is basically the cornmeal equivalent of [making your own self rising flour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/improvised-self-raising-flour).

I have a cornbread recipe [here](http://www.originalsforyou.com/southernrecipes.html) and I have non-self rising corn bread. Do I do the same ratio of baking powwderand salt to make it self rising?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes. That is the basic different between self-rising cornmeal and regular cornmeal.

From Food.com:
http://www.food.com/library/cornmeal-59

Self-rising cornmeal is a white or yellow cornmeal with leavening agents and salt added. 
Substitutions: 1 cup plain cornmeal + 1 1/2 tsp baking powder + 1/2 tsp salt = 1 cup self-rising cornmeal

Answer (score 3):

The questioner said baking soda and the answer says baking powder.  They are not the same thing!  You use baking POWDER, and not baking soda.  1 cup plain cornmeal + 1 1/2 tsp baking powder + 1/2 tsp salt = 1 cup self-rising cornmeal

Comment: Good catch! Baking soda will function if the recipe also includes acidic ingredients, but the ratio will be different.

Comment: @barbara Thanks for pointing that out. For future reference, please comment on the question if the question needs to be edited, or you can propose an edit yourself.