# Can I use German flour Type 405 for a recipe that needs self-rising flour?

Tags: flour, deep-frying

I'm totally new to baking/using flour in general. I'm wondering if Type 405 is enough for a recipe that specifies "self-rising flour".

> Germany's Flour Type 405 is equivalent to pastry flour. Pastry flour is made from soft wheat and has a gluten content of 8-10%. It is soft and ivory in color. Because of its low gluten content, it is best used for baked goods that should have a soft consistency yet still needs some structure, such as muffins, buscuits, pie crust, tart dough, cookies, some sweet yeast doughs, etc.
>
> Pastry flour is available in the U.S. in health food stores, specialty stores, and mail-order businesses. To make a flour with the same gluten content as pastry flour, combine 1 1/3 cups (185g) all-purpose flour and 2/3 cup (90g) cake flour (which is available in most markets and has a gluten content of 6-8%).
>
> [Source](http://www.germanfoodguide.com/flours.cfm)

FWIW, I'm planning to make some home-made munchkins. The recipe doesn't need an oven but is deep fried.

If it is not suitable is there anything I can do/add to make this kind of flour be a suitable substitute for self-rising flour?

Comment: Very related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/improvised-self-raising-flour/10621#10621

Comment: Btw., it may be a good idea to add the recipe you are planning to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword here is “self-rising” - which describes a mix of flour and baking powder.

So if you are going to use 405 instead, which would probably be a good—enough choice (especially as it’s “the standard flour” in German supermarkets), you have to add baking powder. As a rule of thumb, use one pouch (assuming you are in Germany, where that’s the standard unit) per 500g of flour. If your recipe calls for self-raising plus baking powder or baking soda, use the extra amount as well.

I *personally* prefer he German 550 flour as my go-to type, which is closer to what other countries call “all-purpose”, but it may or may not be available at your store. Unless you are making bread and similar goods, 405 will most likely be ok.

Comment: Personally, I usually add less baking powder, maybe 1 pouch per kg of flour - at the prescribed amount, the baked goods usually have a detectable soda flavor (ugh). But of course that depends on what other leavening agents are present.